# More Efficient Web Scraping in Python?

Tags: python, performance, web-scraping, python-requests

I have the code below that successfully scrapes play-by-play data from nba.com and then writes the data to an excel file. It works great for a handful of games, but becomes incredibly slow when trying to scrape an entire season's worth of data.

Is there anything I can implement that will scrape the data more efficiently? I understand it's 500K+ rows of data for an entire season so I'm not expecting lightning speed, but if there's any way to improve my code I definitely want to learn how.

Thanks in advance for any and all help!

```
ids = [str(i) for i in range(21500001,21501231)]

import requests
import pandas as pd

dfs = []

for id in ids:

    game_url = 'http://stats.nba.com/stats/playbyplayv2?EndPeriod=10&EndRange=55800&GameID=00' + id + '&RangeType=2&Season=2015-16&SeasonType=Regular+Season&StartPeriod=1&StartRange=0'

    u_a = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.82 Safari/537.36"
    response = requests.get(game_url, headers={"USER-AGENT":u_a})
    response.raise_for_status()
    game = response.json()['resultSets'][0]['rowSet']
    final = pd.DataFrame(game)
    dfs.append(final)

    finalgame = pd.concat(dfs)

dfs2 = pd.DataFrame(finalgame)

dfs2.to_excel("game15-16.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 1):

You should profile and see where is the bottle neck. In scrapers usually the bottle neck is networking. You could make it faster by making it parallel. For example use [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) that is based on Twisted framework to make concurrent requests.

Comment: An what about exporting it to a cvs file ? As far as reading a csv is quicker, would writing in a csv be quicker too ?